# Can I switch off AutoCorrect/Spell Check/Auto-Capitalize in a specific app?

Tags: ios, ipad

In this particular instance the corrections are unwelcome when I try to use Firebug Lite within Safari. I'd like to turn off the correction options but then it would be globally off so I don't get them in any other apps. Can I do it for just Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, AutoCorrect is a system wide function on iOS. One cannot enable/disable it on a per-program basis.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app that will let you do that called Autocorrect switch. Lets you turn On and OFf the autocorrection option while you email, text or tweet.